# Unable to set height 100% to body tag

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I implement CSS grid to my code to structure the 'main' and 'footer' tag. However, after I set 'grid-template-rows: auto 6.1rem;'

The 'main' tag does not push the 'footer' tag to bottom page, and also height not fulfilling 100% page height, I also set 'body' and 'html' height to height: 100%;

It still not working for me.

[image]

[image]

*Global CSS file - shared.css*

```
/* --------------GLOBAL CSS ---------------------------*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2.7rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 6.1rem;
}

main {
  /* height: 100%; */
  /* margin-top: 2.7rem; */
  /* min-height: calc(100vh - 2.8rem - 6.1rem); */
  /* grid-area: main; */
}

/*Backdrop*/
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*------- TOGGLE BUTTON-------- */
.toggle-button {
  border: none;
  width: 3rem;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button__bar {
  background: #0e4f1f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
  display: block;
}

/* --------------------------------HEADER CSS---------------------------- */
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #07b635;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* grid-area: header; */
}

/*hide header home icon on mobile view*/
.main-div {
  display: none;
}

/*hide header navbar on mobile view*/
.main-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  /*Hide toggle button on desktop view*/
  .toggle-button {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-div {
    display: flex;
  }

  .main-header__brand {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0e4f1f;
  }

  .main-header__brand img {
    height: 1.7rem;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }

  .main-nav__items {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
  }

  .main-nav__item {
    margin: 0 0.6rem;
  }

  .main-nav__item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0e4f1f;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /* .main-nav__item a::after {
    content: "(link)";
    color: red;
  } */

  .main-nav__item a:hover,
  .main-nav__item a:active {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  }

  .main-nav__item--cta a {
    color: white;
    background: #ff1b68;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }

  .main-nav__item--cta a:hover,
  .main-nav__item--cta a:active {
    color: #ff1b68;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: white;
  }
}

/* MOBILE NAVIGATION */
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60%;
  background: white;
  font: inherit;
}

.mobile-nav__items {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mobile-nav__item {
  padding: 0.6rem 0.2rem;
}

.mobile-nav__item a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0e4f1f;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-nav__item--cta a {
  color: white;
  background: #ff1b68;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

/*--------------- BUTTON CSS------------------------- */
.button {
  background: #0e4f1f;
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  border: 1.5px solid #0e4f1f;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover,
.button:active {
  color: #0e4f1f;
  background-color: white;
  /* border-color: white; */
}

/*--------------- FOOTER CSS------------------------- */
.main-footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.main-footer__links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-footer__link {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.main-footer__link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.main-footer__link a:hover,
.main-footer__link a:active {
  color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  .main-footer__links {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .main-footer__link {
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}

.open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

*Main css file, main.css*

```
/* ------------SECTION 1 - PRODUCT OVERVIEW--------------- */
#product-overview {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(22, 11, 5, 0.6) 10%, transparent), url("./images/freedom.jpg"), #ff1b68;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  position: relative;
}

#product-overview h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 3%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  #product-overview h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  #product-overview {
    height: 60%;
    background-position: left 15% bottom 70%;
  }
}

/* --------MODAL------- */
.modal {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: white;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal__title {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.modal__actions {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal__action {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0e4f1f;
  border: 1px solid #0e4f1f;
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.modal__action:hover,
.modal__action:active {
  background: #1a963b;
  border-color: #1a963b;
}

.modal__action--negative {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__action--negative:hover,
.modal__action--negative:active {
  background: #ff5454;
  border-color: #ff5454;
}

/* ----------------SECTION 2 - PRODUCT PLANS--------------- */
.section-title {
  color: rgb(101, 231, 112);
  text-align: center;
}

.plan__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.plan {
  background: #d5ffdc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.plan:last-of-type,
.plan:first-of-type {
  height: 25rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  .plan__list {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .plan {
    width: 20rem;
  }

  .plan--highlighted {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

.plan--highlighted {
  background: #19b84c;
  color: white;
}

.plan__annotation {
  background: white;
  color: #19b84c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.plan__title {
  color: #0e4f1f;
}

.plan__price {
  color: #7d7878;
}

.plan--highlighted .plan__title {
  color: white;
}

.plan--highlighted .plan__price {
  color: #0e4f1f;
}

.plan__features {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.plan__feature {
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}

/* ------------------SECTION 3 - PRODUCT FEATURES-------------- */

#key-features {
  background: #ff1b68;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#key-features .section-title {
  color: white;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.key-features__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key-feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.key-feature__image {
  background: #a69393;
  width: 10.5rem;
  border: 2px solid #5e4e4e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.key-feature__description {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) {
  #key-features {
    margin-top: 4.4rem;
  }

  .key-features__list {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .key-feature {
    width: 27rem;
  }
}
```

*Html home page*

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>uHost</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <style>
        section{
            background: #ff2b27
        }
    </style> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="modal">
      <h1 class="modal__title">Do you want to continue?</h1>
      <div class="modal__actions">
        <a href="start-hosting/index.html" class="modal__action">Yes!</a>
        <button class="modal__action modal__action--negative" type="button">No!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <header class="main-header">
      <button class="toggle-button">
        <span class="toggle-button__bar"></span>
        <span class="toggle-button__bar"></span>
        <span class="toggle-button__bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="main-div">
        <a class="main-header__brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="images/uhost-icon.png" alt="uHost - your favourite Hosting" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav__items">
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--cta">
            <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <nav class="mobile-nav">
      <ul class="mobile-nav__items">
        <li class="mobile-nav__item">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav__item">
          <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav__item">
          <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav__item mobile-nav__item--cta">
          <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <section id="product-overview">
        <h1>Get the freedom you deserve</h1>
      </section>
      <section id="plans">
        <h1 class="section-title">Choose your plan</h1>
        <div class="plan__list">
          <article class="plan">
            <h1 class="plan__title">FREE</h1>
            <h2 class="plan__price">$0/month</h2>
            <h3>For hobby projects or small teams</h3>
            <ul class="plan__features">
              <li class="plan__feature">1 Workspace</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Unlimited traffic</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">10GB Storage</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Basic Support</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <button class="button">CHOOSE PLAN</button>
            </div>
          </article>
          <article class="plan plan--highlighted">
            <h1 class="plan__annotation">RECOMMENDED</h1>
            <h1 class="plan__title">PLUS</h1>
            <h2 class="plan__price">$29/month</h2>
            <h3>For ambitious projects</h3>
            <ul class="plan__features">
              <li class="plan__feature">5 Workspace</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Unlimited traffic</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">100GB Storage</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Plus Support</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <button class="button">CHOOSE PLAN</button>
            </div>
          </article>
          <article class="plan">
            <h1 class="plan__title">PREMIUM</h1>
            <h2 class="plan__price">$99/month</h2>
            <h3>For ambitious projects</h3>
            <ul class="plan__features">
              <li class="plan__feature">10 Workspace</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Unlimited traffic</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Unlimited Storage</li>
              <li class="plan__feature">Priority Support</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <button class="button">CHOOSE PLAN</button>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="key-features">
        <h1 class="section-title">Many Good Reasons to Stick Around</h1>
        <ul class="key-features__list">
          <li class="key-feature">
            <div class="key-feature__image">
            </div>
            <p class="key-feature__description">3,699,000 Trusting Customers</p>
          </li>
          <li class="key-feature">
            <div class="key-feature__image">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                <path style="fill: #69788d" d="M248,0H8C3.582,0,0,3.582,0,8v496c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h240c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8V8  C256,3.582,252.418,0,248,0z" />
                <path style="fill: #56677e" d="M24,504V8c0-4.418,3.582-8,8-8H8C3.582,0,0,3.582,0,8v496c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h24  C27.582,512,24,508.418,24,504z" />
                <g>
                  <rect x="0" y="112" style="fill: #435670" width="256" height="16" />
                  <rect x="0" y="240" style="fill: #435670" width="256" height="16" />
                </g>
                <path style="fill: #f7c14d" d="M128,392c-22.056,0-40,17.944-40,40s17.944,40,40,40s40-17.944,40-40S150.056,392,128,392z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M128,408c-13.233,0-24,10.767-24,24s10.767,24,24,24s24-10.767,24-24S141.233,408,128,408z" />
                <path style="fill: #f7c14d" d="M128,392c-2.739,0-5.414,0.278-8,0.805V424c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8v-31.195  C133.414,392.278,130.739,392,128,392z" />
                <g>
                  <path style="fill: #435670" d="M216,288H40c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h176c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S220.418,288,216,288z" />
                  <path style="fill: #435670" d="M216,328H40c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h176c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S220.418,328,216,328z" />
                  <path style="fill: #435670" d="M216,368H40c-4.418,0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8,8-8h176c4.418,0,8,3.582,8,8S220.418,368,216,368z" />
                  <path style="fill: #435670" d="M216,16H40c-4.418,0-8,3.582-8,8v64c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h176c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8V24   C224,19.582,220.418,16,216,16z" />
                </g>
                <rect x="48" y="32" style="fill: #56677e" width="160" height="48" />
                <path style="fill: #435670" d="M216,144H40c-4.418,0-8,3.582-8,8v64c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h176c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8v-64  C224,147.582,220.418,144,216,144z" />
                <rect x="48" y="160" style="fill: #56677e" width="160" height="48" />
                <path
                  style="fill: #f09b24"
                  d="M511.747,180.237c-0.194-6.537-8.107-10.107-13.135-5.894c-5.6,4.693-42.904,21.282-98.514,21.282  c-33.45,0-64.625-20.999-64.929-21.206c-2.9-1.991-6.764-1.85-9.512,0.346c-2.677,2.135-27.201,20.86-63.793,20.86  c-55.607,0-92.914-16.589-98.515-21.282c-5.028-4.211-12.941-0.645-13.135,5.894c-1.634,54.834,4.655,105.941,18.693,151.903  c12.096,39.604,29.759,74.047,52.497,102.373c27.538,34.304,62.743,59.882,104.66,76.045c3.069,1.918,6.757,1.921,9.83,0  c41.917-16.163,77.122-41.741,104.66-76.045c22.738-28.326,40.401-62.77,52.497-102.373  C507.092,286.179,513.381,235.071,511.747,180.237z"
                />
                <path
                  style="fill: #f7c14d"
                  d="M476.21,221.226c-1.953-1.631-4.568-2.235-7.036-1.628c-21.686,5.327-44.926,8.028-69.075,8.028  c-25.926,0-49.633-8.975-64.955-16.504c-2.307-1.134-5.016-1.091-7.284,0.116c-14.059,7.477-36.919,16.388-65.994,16.388  c-24.153,0-47.394-2.701-69.075-8.028c-5.155-1.268-10.221,2.966-9.894,8.261c2.077,33.693,7.668,65.635,16.616,94.935  c22.774,74.565,66.139,126.334,128.888,153.868c2.032,0.891,4.397,0.891,6.43,0c61.777-27.107,104.716-78.876,127.62-153.868  c8.948-29.3,14.539-61.241,16.616-94.935C479.224,225.319,478.163,222.856,476.21,221.226z"
                />
                <path
                  style="fill: #ffdb66"
                  d="M331.609,451.727c-52.604-25.289-89.304-70.987-109.144-135.944  c-6.532-21.39-11.162-44.336-13.82-68.447c17.133,2.852,34.952,4.291,53.22,4.291c29.394,0,53.376-7.793,69.978-15.561  c17.44,7.736,41.656,15.561,68.256,15.561c18.267,0,36.085-1.439,53.219-4.291c-2.659,24.112-7.288,47.06-13.82,68.448  C419.545,381.108,383.27,426.805,331.609,451.727z"
                />
                <g>
                  <path
                    style="fill: #2c9dd4"
                    d="M479.066,227.858c0.157-2.539-0.903-5.002-2.856-6.633s-4.568-2.235-7.036-1.628   c-21.686,5.327-44.926,8.028-69.075,8.028c-25.926,0-49.633-8.975-64.955-16.504c-1.057-0.52-2.2-0.78-3.345-0.806l-0.072,133.351   h123.601c2.556-6.746,4.933-13.702,7.123-20.874C471.398,293.493,476.989,261.552,479.066,227.858z"
                  />
                  <path style="fill: #2c9dd4" d="M206.658,343.667c24.153,63.42,65.028,108.108,121.743,132.995c1.031,0.452,2.147,0.673,3.263,0.666   l0.063-133.661H206.658z" />
                </g>
                <g>
                  <path style="fill: #3cbde8" d="M439.497,315.783c6.532-21.389,11.161-44.336,13.82-68.448c-17.134,2.852-34.952,4.291-53.219,4.291   c-26.6,0-50.815-7.824-68.256-15.561l-0.116,107.601h97.758C433.179,334.807,436.524,325.518,439.497,315.783z" />
                  <path style="fill: #3cbde8" d="M232.523,343.667c21.144,50.298,54.363,86.56,99.087,108.06l0.117-108.06H232.523z" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p class="key-feature__description">99.99% Uptime Guarantee</p>
          </li>
          <li class="key-feature">
            <div class="key-feature__image">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                <path style="fill: #8e9aa9" d="M168,200c-4.418,0-8,3.582-8,8v120h-17.376c-3.302-9.311-12.194-16-22.624-16  c-13.234,0-24,10.767-24,24s10.766,24,24,24c10.429,0,19.321-6.689,22.624-16H168c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8V208  C176,203.582,172.418,200,168,200z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M120,328c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S124.411,328,120,328z" />
                <path style="fill: #56677e" d="M208,200c-4.418,0-8,3.582-8,8v184H94.624C91.322,382.689,82.43,376,72,376  c-13.234,0-24,10.767-24,24s10.766,24,24,24c10.429,0,19.321-6.689,22.624-16H208c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8V208  C216,203.582,212.418,200,208,200z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M72,392c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S76.411,392,72,392z" />
                <path style="fill: #69788d" d="M240,208c-4.418,0-8,3.582-8,8v239H47.24c-2.671-10.34-12.078-18-23.24-18c-13.234,0-24,10.767-24,24  s10.766,24,24,24c9.666,0,18.009-5.747,21.809-14H240c4.418,0,8-3.582,8-8V216C248,211.582,244.418,208,240,208z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M24,453c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S28.411,453,24,453z" />
                <path style="fill: #69788d" d="M488,464c-10.429,0-19.321,6.689-22.624,16H280V208c0-4.418-3.582-8-8-8s-8,3.582-8,8v280  c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h193.376c3.302,9.311,12.194,16,22.624,16c13.234,0,24-10.767,24-24S501.234,464,488,464z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M488,480c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S492.411,480,488,480z" />
                <path style="fill: #56677e" d="M456,408c-10.429,0-19.321,6.689-22.624,16H312V208c0-4.418-3.582-8-8-8s-8,3.582-8,8v224  c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h129.376c3.302,9.311,12.194,16,22.624,16c13.234,0,24-10.767,24-24S469.234,408,456,408z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M456,424c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S460.411,424,456,424z" />
                <path style="fill: #8e9aa9" d="M416,344c-10.429,0-19.321,6.689-22.624,16H352V208c0-4.418-3.582-8-8-8s-8,3.582-8,8v160  c0,4.418,3.582,8,8,8h49.376c3.302,9.311,12.194,16,22.624,16c13.234,0,24-10.767,24-24S429.234,344,416,344z" />
                <path style="fill: #ffdb66" d="M416,360c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8s8-3.589,8-8S420.411,360,416,360z" />
                <path style="fill: #3cbde8" d="M362,88c-8.741,0-17.231,1.751-25.06,5.085C337.646,88.797,338,84.43,338,80  c0-44.112-35.888-80-80-80c-42.823,0-77.895,33.816-79.909,76.149C170.393,73.415,162.244,72,154,72c-39.701,0-72,32.299-72,72  s32.299,72,72,72h208c35.29,0,64-28.71,64-64S397.29,88,362,88z" />
                <path style="fill: #2c9dd4" d="M368,200H160c-39.701,0-72-32.299-72-72c0-5.863,0.721-11.559,2.05-17.019  C84.918,120.88,82,132.102,82,144c0,39.701,32.299,72,72,72h208c30.389,0,55.88-21.296,62.379-49.743  C413.565,186.327,392.352,200,368,200z" />
                <path style="fill: #2a7db5" d="M256,128c-13.234,0-24,10.767-24,24s10.766,24,24,24c13.233,0,24-10.767,24-24S269.233,128,256,128z" />
                <path style="fill: #2c9dd4" d="M256,144c-4.411,0-8,3.589-8,8s3.589,8,8,8c4.411,0,8-3.589,8-8S260.411,144,256,144z" />
                <g>
                  <path
                    style="fill: #c5f1fa"
                    d="M221.755,87.695c-2.994,0-5.864-1.688-7.233-4.572c-1.894-3.991-0.194-8.763,3.798-10.657   C230.157,66.849,242.834,64,256,64c13.166,0,25.844,2.849,37.68,8.466c3.992,1.895,5.692,6.666,3.798,10.657   s-6.666,5.692-10.657,3.798C277.144,82.328,266.774,80,256,80c-10.774,0-21.144,2.328-30.821,6.921   C224.072,87.446,222.904,87.695,221.755,87.695z"
                  />
                  <path
                    style="fill: #c5f1fa"
                    d="M276.545,116.618c-1.148,0-2.316-0.249-3.424-0.774C267.745,113.293,261.985,112,256,112   c-5.985,0-11.745,1.293-17.121,3.844c-3.991,1.895-8.763,0.192-10.657-3.798c-1.894-3.992-0.193-8.764,3.798-10.657   C239.557,97.813,247.625,96,256,96c8.376,0,16.444,1.813,23.98,5.389c3.991,1.894,5.692,6.665,3.798,10.657   C282.41,114.93,279.539,116.618,276.545,116.618z"
                  />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p class="key-feature__description">Lighting Fast CDN</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <nav>
        <ul class="main-footer__links">
          <li class="main-footer__link">
            <a href="#">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-footer__link">
            <a href="#">Term of Use</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </footer>
    <script src="shared.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not working with limited code and images. Can you reproduce the problem here (with full code)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I reproduced full code global css and main css file

Comment: I discovered that problem lying at 'Product Overview' Css code, I commented 'Product Overview' html, footer get pushed well down to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

The issue lying at `main.css` file, specifically at `#product-overview` selector
I changed `height: 33%` to `height: 33vh`
and in media-query: `height: 60%` to `height: 60vh;`

Css `body` tag I changed to bellow

```css
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2.7rem auto fit-content(8rem);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(220px, 1fr)); /*=> without this line page width got overflow, don't know why too*/
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "main"
      "footer";
  }
```

Css `main` tag code edited

```css
#product-overview {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(22, 11, 5, 0.6) 10%, transparent), url("./images/freedom.jpg"), #ff1b68;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) {    
    #product-overview {
      height: 60vh;
      background-position: left 15% bottom 70%;
    }
  }
```

I removed `height` set for `html,body,main` tags and code working well.
However, to be honest I have no idea why changed from `%` to `vh` unit make all my code working, as well as why `footer` tag got pushed down to bottom.